# How to Stop MediaPlayer

Tags: android

i have a problem. my media player doesn't stop even activity has stopped. so i confuse why media player doesn't stop. media player immediately playing until a mp3 finish. here my code

```
public class Isi_TakbiratulIhram extends Activity{
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.isitakbiratulihram);

    ImageButton iftitah1=(ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.takbiratulihram1);
    iftitah1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            go();
         }
        public void go(){

            if(mp != null ){
                mp.stop();
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mp.seekTo(0);

                mp = null;

            }
            else {
                mp=MediaPlayer.create(Isi_TakbiratulIhram.this, R.raw.iftitah1);


            mp.start();


            }




 }});
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override Activity `onPause()` method for stoping Media Player :

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
```

Comment: @Ardi : onPause() or onStop()  both is method of Activity so just put this method after onCreate method of activity. i you have any issue then edit your post with full code,i will do for you.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onPause()` or `onStop()` and stop it there:

```
@Override protected void onPause()
{
    if(mp != null ){
        mp.stop();
        // mp.release(); ??
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When user stops an Activity the state of activity can go to onStop() state,SO it is required to stop any ongoing tasks like music playing here.So in android programming it's required go handle all states like onRestart(), onResume(), onStop(), onPause(), onDestroy() for proper functioning of the program.

For handling stopping and restarting of activity visit : 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html